# Ordering custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a page on my site that has customer testimonials. Each testimonial is a custom post. I want to order the testimonials arbitrarily. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I previously did this, was by adding a custom field to my CPTs, and ordering by that value when I fetched my posts with WP_Query.

```
 $myquery = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
      'meta_key' => 'my_custom_field_name',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value'
      )
 );
```

However, I believe if you add 'page-attributes' to your 'supports' parameter when you register your CPT, you have the 'Order' field available, which you can order by.

```
 $myquery = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
      'orderby' => 'menu_order'
      )
 );
```